# How to make Ubuntu 16.04.1 installation USB drive boot in legacy mode?

Tags: boot, live-usb, startup-disk-creator, startup-disk

How to make Ubuntu 16.04.1 installation USB drive boot in legacy mode?
I used Startup Disk Creator, but USB won't boot on a laptop which does not support UEFI. I put USB drive as first boot choice in BIOS.